# Postgre/PostGIS - How to find points inside an area

Tags: postgis, postgresql, point-in-polygon

I have a database of clients/users with their coordinates.
I would like to select all clients within the marked area.

Query:

```
SELECT * FROM clients
INNER JOIN polygons 
ON polygons.polygon @> clients.geo_point
```

works fine for areas where there is not empty area inside. 
If there is en empty space inside like on the picture, blank area is selected as well.

[image]

If the area looks like this:

[image]

Everything works fine.

Which query and which spatial function should I use to select clients correctly?

Comment: You could try using ST_Contains instead of @>. I have no idea how @> is handled internally, it is actually a Postgres rather than Postgis function, but ST_Contains handles polygons with inner rings correctly.

Answer (score 2):

`@>` is not a [PostGIS bounding box operator](http://postgis.net/docs/reference.html#Operators). It is a [PostgreSQL geometric operator](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-geometry.html) with the `box` type. So essentially, the query in your question casts the PostGIS bounding box to PostgreSQL box types. Box types are not equivalent to point-in-polygon operators required for your problem. Furthermore, mixing PostGIS types and PostgreSQL geometric types is never recommended.

---

Try using [ST_Within](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Within.html):

```
SELECT * FROM clients
INNER JOIN polygons 
ON ST_Within(clients.geo_point, polygons.polygon)
```

Or [ST_DWithin](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_DWithin.html) if you need a virtual buffer using a distance threshold. Make sure the tables have spatial indexes for good performance. There are many other spatial relation operators available.